# ExpandableListView - onItemLongClick - getPackedPositionChild always returns 0

Tags: expandablelistview

`ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id)` below is always returning 0. The group position is correct, but I can't get the correct child position.  What's wrong with the code below?

```
@Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
            int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);
            int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id);
            // do something
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

A bit of addition code is needed.  You must first convert the input Integer-based flat List position to a Long-based Packed Position.  Tested code follows:

```
@Override   
public boolean onItemLongClick( AdapterView<?>    parent,
                                View              view,
                                int               position,
                                long              id) {

    //  convert the input flat list position to a packed position
    long packedPosition = m_expandableListView.getExpandableListPosition(position);

    int itemType        = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(packedPosition); 
    int groupPosition   = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPosition);
    int childPosition   = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(packedPosition);


    //  GROUP-item clicked
    if (itemType == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
        //  ...
        onGroupLongClick(groupPosition);
    }

    //  CHILD-item clicked
    else if (itemType == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
        //  ...
        onChildLongClick(groupPosition, childPosition);
    }


    //  return "true" to consume event - "false" to allow default processing
    return false;
}
```